# JSQMessagesViewController show message time for each message

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am stuck with JSQMessagesViewController and searching for solution to show message time for each message similar like Whatsup or Viber shows. 
Thanks folks!

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/issues/730

Answer (score 0):

You can insert your own label between bottom label and text view. But pay attention to constraints.
[image]